# if($(var).css('display') == "block") with slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to change an icon shown on the option title (`.option-title`) when the content below e.g. (`.add_to_rotation`) is toggled up or down. While down, the close (`.retract-icon`) button should be shown, and while up the add (`.expand-icon`) should be shown.

The problem I think lies in the delay from the time at which `slideToggle` is called, until the property it's called on changes from `display: hidden` to `display: block` and vice versa.

**Here's my code:**

```
$('.option-title').click( function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('id');
      $('.' + name).slideToggle('slow');
      if($('.' + name).css('display') == "block") {
        $(this).html("Add to Rotation? <div class=\"retract-icon\">");
      } else {
        $(this).html("Add to Rotation? <div class=\"expand-icon\">");
      }
  });
```

The first part of the `if()` conditional executes fine, so the condition must be considered true, but when clicked again, the first condition is still considered true, and the contents of `.option-title` doesn't change.

How could I have it work as per my description above?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ;).

Comment: Try, `if($(...).is(':visible')) { ... }`

Comment: Your selector of id/name looks strange: it looks like you're doing a bit of a hacky thing, and have an element like `<div id="foo">` that is finding anything with `class="foo"` and hiding/showing it. Is this your intent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two easy ways to solve this.

Instead of using slideToggle, detect the condition first, and then use either slideUp or slideDown, which will make your message appear while the slide is happening:

```
$('.option-title').click( function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('id');
      var slider = $('.' + name); // shortcut to the element that's being slid. There's probably a better variable name you can use but I don't know the context
      if(slider.css('display') == "block") {
            slider.slideUp('slow');
            $(this).html("Add to Rotation? <div class=\"retract-icon\">");
      } else {
            slider.slideDown('slow');
            $(this).html("Add to Rotation? <div class=\"expand-icon\">");
      }
  });
```

Or use a callback, which will mean your message won't appear until after the slide is done:

```
$('.option-title').click( function() {
      var name = $(this).attr('id');
      var slider = $('.' + name); // shortcut to the element that's being slid. There's probably a better variable name you can use but I don't know the context
      slider.slideToggle('slow', function() {
        if(slider.css('display') == "block") {
            $(this).html("Add to Rotation? <div class=\"retract-icon\">");
        } else {
            $(this).html("Add to Rotation? <div class=\"expand-icon\">");
        }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem *could be* that you are mixing `classes` and `ids`.

You retrieve an `id` here

`var name = $(this).attr('id');`

but then search for a `class` here

`$('.' + name).slideToggle('slow');`

Not sure that is what you are trying to do.

If not, change `$('.' + name)` to `$('#' + name)`

Comment: That's not the problem. `.option-title` has an id which is the same as the class name of another element. Stupid I know.

Comment: In that case, I would use the answer from @gregmac re a `callback function`.